# upload to JWPlayer platform from within browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Can anyone of  point me to a JavaScript library or a piece of code that implements uploading video file using JWPlayer Platform API? There is a PHP example on their site (link on this page):

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1435970-upload-videos-with-the-platform-api

but not much about the JavaScript approach.

I would be very grateful for any information that can save me time. It is hard to believe nobody has done this so far, but I could not find a JS library that does the upload. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is for a site that will not be exposed outside a small company, and security (keeping the keys secret) is not a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no JavaScript approach for uploading files to the platform. Our API kits for this only use PHP or Python. Using JavaScript is not possible because you need to set your account's API Key/Secret, which would be exposed to the public if using JavaScript. It doesn't make sense to use JavaScript for this purpose.